# Удалить часть html кода через sed(или любой другой вариант который можно использовать)

Tags: html, linux, unix, sed, find

Есть много файлов в каталоге и подкаталоге. Нужно удалить определенную часть из кода. Вот часть кода:

```
<a href="https://vk.com/profildoors.factory" class="footer-content-social-network-link"  target="_blank">       <img src="../images/icon-vk.png" alt="icon social network"  /> </a>
```

Вот что уже пробывал сделать:

```
find -type f -name \*.html | xargs sed -i'' '/<a href="https:\/\/vk.com\/profildoors.factory" class="footer-content-social-network-link" target="_blank">/,/<\/a>/d'
```

Также пробывал заменить на пустые символы. Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Comment: Опишите более подробно что должно удалиться и что хотите оставить

Comment: Не получится. Только для очень частных случаев. Проще всего это делать с помощью библиотеки `lxml` что в Питоне. Как пример работы с `ElementTree`:  https://pastebin.com/htRjPBb0

Comment: хочу удалить вот этот участок кода. <a href="https://vk.com/profildoors.factory" class="footer-content-social-network-link"  target="_blank">       <img src="../images/icon-vk.png" alt="icon social network"  /> </a>

Comment: `find -type f -name "*.html" -execdir sed 's~<a href="vk.com/profildoors.factory" class="footer-content-social-network-link" target="_blank"> <img src="../images/icon-vk.png" alt="icon social network" /> </a>~~g' {} \;` Если вывод команды будет корректный то поставьте sed ключ -i

Answer (score 0):

Команду *sed* надо записать как-то так:

```
sed -i'' -e 's/Что заменить/На что заменить/g'
```

Если Вы хотите **убрать** часть строки, то "На что заменить" становится строкой нулевой длины:

```
sed -i'' -e 's/Что затереть//g'
```

Comment: Но оно не заработает с html кодом который я предоставил из-за разделителей.

Comment: @RamanAktsisiuk Если Вы напишите регулярное выражение **правильно**, почему же не заработает ?! В приведённом Вами тексте, сам формат ызова *sed* неправильный.  Кроме того, в кусочке текста *https://vk.com/* Вы зачем-то заэкранировали прямые слэши (не надо) и **не** заэкранировали точку (обязательно нужно!).  Почитайте синтаксис регулярных выражение хотя бы  тут :  https://tproger.ru/articles/regexp-for-beginners/

Comment: спасибо, почитаю.